# Bash script to ping remote machine hanging

Tags: bash

I have a bash functions file named `ping` that has a single function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ping() {
  ping -c 1 $i.local
}
```

This file is loaded by another bash file named `pinger` and attempts to use the ping function to contact multiple remote machines

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. /home/ping #load ping function

REMOTES=('remote1' 'remote2' 'remote3')

for i in "${REMOTES[@]}"; do

    ping $i

done
```

When I run `./pinger` it hangs until I `CTRL-C`. I am able to successfully ping the remote machines if I manually type `ping -c 1 remote1.local` in command line. Where is the issue with the script?

EDIT: I found the problem to be naming the function "ping." When the function is named anything else, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Add `which ping` after sourcing your script. (It's also a bad idea to add a function or binary named `test`, BTW). Also, you can run your script using `bash -x pinger` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be naming the function "ping." When the function is named anything else, it seems to work fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pingRemote() {
  ping -c 1 $i.local
}
```

.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. /home/ping #load ping function

REMOTES=('remote1' 'remote2' 'remote3')

for i in "${REMOTES[@]}"; do

    pingRemote $i

done
```

Comment: Your function was finding itself before the /usr/bin/ping command on disk, so it was constantly calling itself.

Comment: On bash, you could have a function `ping` and also invoke the real executable with `command ping` or the full path `/bin/ping`.